# How to parse fields from within an XML family & map to its right parent when there's no specific field to parameterize the parsed strings?

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, hive, hiveql

In my input XML, there are multiple "Parent" families within Parents. In each Parent, there could be single or multiple "ChildRoot" families within ChildRoots. There are 4 fields that need to be parsed in this hierarchy. How could this be achieved without cross joins happening, with the help of Hive XPATH functions? In this case, there's no specific field to parameterize the parsed strings, in order to map to its right parent (Parents/Parent/ChildRoots/ChildRoot/).

```
<Parents>
    <Parent>
        <ChildRoots>
            <ChildRoot>
                <FieldA>Field A info1</FieldA>
                <FieldB>Field B info1</FieldB>
                <FieldC>Field C info1</FieldC>
                <FieldD>Field D info1</FieldD>
            </ChildRoot>
        </ChildRoots>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ChildRoots>
            <ChildRoot>
                <FieldA>Field A info2</FieldA>
                <FieldC>Field C info2</FieldC>
                <FieldD>Field D info2</FieldD>
            </ChildRoot>
            <ChildRoot>
                <FieldA>Field A info3</FieldA>
                <FieldB>Field B info3</FieldB>
                <FieldD>Field D info3</FieldD>
            </ChildRoot>
        </ChildRoots>
    </Parent>
</Parents>
```

Expected output:

```
FieldA          FieldB          FieldC          FieldD
Field A info1   Field B info1   Field C info1   Field D info1
Field A info2                   Field C info2   Field D info2
Field A info3   Field B info3                   Field D info3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using count() XPATH function you can calculate the number of elements on each level. For example `XPATH_INT(xml, 'count(/Parents/Parent)')` gives `2`.
Generate rows for each level using lateral view posexplode and use exploded position to parametrize XPATHs, so all of them will have conformed position indexes and cross joins will not happen.

In this example `<Parent>` has only single child `<ChildRoots>`, you can remove calculation of count and explode if it can be the only `<ChildRoots>` in each Parent, this will simplify code a bit. My code allows multiple `<ChildRoots>` per  `<Parent>`.

Demo:

```
with mytable as (
select '<Parents>
    <Parent>
        <ChildRoots>
            <ChildRoot>
                <FieldA>Field A info1</FieldA>
                <FieldB>Field B info1</FieldB>
                <FieldC>Field C info1</FieldC>
                <FieldD>Field D info1</FieldD>
            </ChildRoot>
        </ChildRoots>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ChildRoots>
            <ChildRoot>
                <FieldA>Field A info2</FieldA>
                <FieldC>Field C info2</FieldC>
                <FieldD>Field D info2</FieldD>
            </ChildRoot>
            <ChildRoot>
                <FieldA>Field A info3</FieldA>
                <FieldB>Field B info3</FieldB>
                <FieldD>Field D info3</FieldD>
            </ChildRoot>
        </ChildRoots>
    </Parent>
</Parents>
' as xml
)

select --Get ChildRoot count and generate rows with position index, build final XPATH
       --xml, parent_pos, ChildRoots_pos, 
       --cr.pos+1 as ChildRoot_pos, --this expression used in xpath as is:
       XPATH_STRING(xml, concat('/Parents/Parent[',parent_pos,']/ChildRoots[',ChildRoots_pos,']/ChildRoot[',cr.pos+1,']/FieldA/text()')) as FieldA,
       XPATH_STRING(xml, concat('/Parents/Parent[',parent_pos,']/ChildRoots[',ChildRoots_pos,']/ChildRoot[',cr.pos+1,']/FieldB/text()')) as FieldB,
       XPATH_STRING(xml, concat('/Parents/Parent[',parent_pos,']/ChildRoots[',ChildRoots_pos,']/ChildRoot[',cr.pos+1,']/FieldC/text()')) as FieldC,
       XPATH_STRING(xml, concat('/Parents/Parent[',parent_pos,']/ChildRoots[',ChildRoots_pos,']/ChildRoot[',cr.pos+1,']/FieldD/text()')) as FieldD
from
( --Get ChildRoots count and generate rows with position index
select xml, parent_pos, crs.pos+1 as ChildRoots_pos
       --XPATH_INT(xml, concat('count(/Parents/Parent[',parent_pos,']/ChildRoots)')) as ChildRoots_cnt  
from
  ( --Get Parent count and generate rows with position index
    select  xml, p.pos+1 as parent_pos
          --XPATH_INT(xml, 'count(/Parents/Parent)') as Parent_cnt
     from mytable lateral view outer posexplode(split(space(XPATH_INT(xml, 'count(/Parents/Parent)')-1),'')) p as  pos, x
   ) p lateral view outer posexplode(split(space(XPATH_INT(xml, concat('count(/Parents/Parent[',parent_pos,']/ChildRoots)'))-1),'')) crs as  pos, x 
) crs lateral view outer posexplode(split(space(XPATH_INT(xml, concat('count(/Parents/Parent[',parent_pos,']/ChildRoots[',ChildRoots_pos,']/ChildRoot)'))-1),'')) cr as  pos, x
```

Result:

```
fielda           fieldb           fieldc           fieldd
Field A info1    Field B info1    Field C info1    Field D info1
Field A info2                     Field C info2    Field D info2
Field A info3    Field B info3                     Field D info3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the demo & details! However could you please shed some light on the significance of "-1" in the query within POSEXPLODE()? Is it to reduce the number of spaces by 1? Thanks in advance!    @leftjoin

Comment: @RKR Just check what `select size(split(space(2),''))` returns  --for two spaces it returns 3 because empty space before, empty space between two spaces, empty space at the end, so split() returns array of 3 elements. And we need 2.

Comment: @RKR also pos index produced by posexplode starts from 0, and index in xpath starts from 1, this is why we need to use pos+1 in xpath

Answer (score 0):

Needed fields could be found by its name as

```
xmllint --xpath '/Parents/Parent[1]/ChildRoots/ChildRoot[1]/child::*[name()="FieldA" or name()="FieldB" or name()="FieldC" or name()="FieldD"]' test.xml ; echo
# <FieldA>Field A info1</FieldA><FieldB>Field B info1</FieldB><FieldC>Field C info1</FieldC><FieldD>Field D info1</FieldD>

xmllint --xpath '/Parents/Parent[2]/ChildRoots/ChildRoot[1]/child::*[name()="FieldA" or name()="FieldB" or name()="FieldC" or name()="FieldD"]' test.xml ; echo
# <FieldA>Field A info2</FieldA><FieldC>Field C info2</FieldC><FieldD>Field D info2</FieldD>

xmllint --xpath '/Parents/Parent[2]/ChildRoots/ChildRoot[2]/child::*[name()="FieldA" or name()="FieldB" or name()="FieldC" or name()="FieldD"]' test.xml ; echo
# <FieldA>Field A info3</FieldA><FieldB>Field B info3</FieldB><FieldD>Field D info3</FieldD>
```